# How to make my css button to be like this one on Google

Tags: html, css

I found this button on the Google Store website: 
https://store.google.com/?utm_source=hp_header&utm_medium=google_oo&utm_campaign=GS100042#social-modal

[Image of The Google Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiTsr.png)

I want to use that **HOVER ANIMATION** for these two buttons on my website: https://www.varomy.com/

[Image of The Buttons on My Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytBfX.png)

What CSS codes should I add or change?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks to me like a [Ripple from Google's Material library](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/).  See the [demo page](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/ripple).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background, transition` and `transform`.

```css
.btn_g {display:block;position:relative;width:46px;height:46px;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:50%;overflow:hidden}

.btn_g:after {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;width:46px;height:46px;background:#000;content:'';
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    transition:.2s;
    opacity:0;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.btn_g:hover:after {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity:1;
}

.btn_g:before {position:absolute;top:16px;left:16px;z-index:10;content:'';width:15px;height:15px;background:url(https://mannequin.storage.googleapis.com/2018/modal/exit.svg) no-repeat}
.btn_g:hover:before {background-image:url(https://mannequin.storage.googleapis.com/2018/modal/exit-white.svg)}
```

```html
<a href="#none" class="btn_g"></a>
```

Comment: I need the hover animation, not just an image

Comment: Still not the same. I want the black part to be expanding from the middle

Comment: @VictorLi Please check again!

Comment: @VictorLi My pleasure :)

Comment: Hi, I just adjusted my website. Now it works, but on my website, the texts in the button are not shown when hovering. https://www.varomy.com. Can you help me solve that?

Comment: @VictorLi OK. You have to add styles to the TEXT, like this : `<span style="position:relative;z-index:10">Sign Up</span>`

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this using `background`

```
.btn_g {display:block;position:relative;width:46px;height:46px;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:50%;transition:.2s}
.btn_g:before {position:absolute;top:16px;left:16px;content:'';width:15px;height:15px;background:url(https://mannequin.storage.googleapis.com/2018/modal/exit.svg) no-repeat}
.btn_g:hover {background-color:#000}
.btn_g:hover:before {background-image:url(https://mannequin.storage.googleapis.com/2018/modal/exit-white.svg)}
```

Html :

```
<a href="#none" class="btn_g"></a>
```